# Audio Recording Interrupt iOS 6 Error

Tags: ios6, core-audio

Apple's demo project aurioTouch2 demonstrates the same iOS-6 problem I have with handling audio interrupts when in a recording mode.

The scenario is very specific. When in an audio recording mode, a phone call is made, and then is answered (declining the call does not cause the bug). Then, after hanging up, the app returns to focus and fails to continue recording.

The error message is: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (2003329396)
This error code translates helpfully to the word 'what'.

The aurioTouch2 project was an update for iOS-5, but isn't working for iOS-6. Seems a fairly  critical bug for my app, since the device is a "phone".

I've tried every sensible variation without luck. Anyone come across the same issue ?
Many thanks.

**Edit:** Here's the code that fixed it for me. The fix is noted in the comments. Not exactly elegant, but I'll take anything at this point.

This method gets called at some point *after* the app has returned to an active state. I have the interrupt-end trigger set a flag, and then later when things are alive again, I check the flag and then call this method here.

```
-(void) handleEndInterruption {
    // Reset audio session
    UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    AudioSessionSetProperty ( kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (category), &category );

    // Reactivate the current audio session
    AudioSessionSetActive(YES);

    // Do this, and fail with: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (2003329396)
    [self createAUProcessingGraph];
    [self initializeAndStartProcessingGraph];

    // Do it a second time and it works
    AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
    AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
    [self createAUProcessingGraph];
    [self initializeAndStartProcessingGraph];

    // Restore open al context
    alcMakeContextCurrent([AudioDispatcher sharedInstance].audioContext);

    // 'unpause' my context
    alcProcessContext([AudioDispatcher sharedInstance].audioContext);
}
```

Comment: I've seen the same issue but found no workaround. Present on iPhone4 running iOS 6.0.

Comment: In my own code I can pin it down to this call here:
alcMakeContextCurrent(context);

No error is present by checking this:
err = alGetError();

I wonder if it's possible to just tear down the whole audio setup and put it back together, instead of trying to be graceful about it.

Comment: My workaround that seems to be working is by first deactivating the audio session, then re-activating the audio session, then tearing down and setting up the audio unit etc. And of course that has to be done after the host app has returned to active state.

Comment: Hi, sounds promising. Would you be able to post some sample code to clarify the workaround ? Would be most grateful. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. For me it was doing what you said above, twice. Basically, I'd tear everything down, set it up - it would fail with the inscrutable error code. Then I'd just do it a second time and it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GuptonMubes you should post your solution as an answer and not as a edit.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and found a solution.

Using the core telephony framework to detect the incoming call, I stop the recording "ungracefully" by closing the file, without touching the audio queues. Then, when the app resumes, I show the recording in a paused state, the user is then able to resume the recording. In the meantime, I restarted all my core audio queues.

Be careful with the `callEventHandler` of `CTCallCenter` if you're using ARC. It is not released properly so remember to set it to `nil`.